# Indicate to a client that the servlet is busy

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I'm testing my Java servlet (deployed on Glassfish 4) with a client. My servlet returns a binary stream which can be quite large (depends on the request).

Processing the request takes a bit of time due to computations on my end. The problem is this: Because the client gets no response in due time, he sends an additional request which screws up my servlet; I get IllegalStateExceptions because it's both writing to the stream and trying to send an error. How can I tell the client that I received his request successfully, but he has to wait a bit? And without writing the actual data to the stream? I can only get the data in one fell swoop, no buffering possible on this end.

Would it for instance make sense to write a zero byte array to the output stream?
Is there a HTTP-status which I can send back?

Or are there any other solutions?

I can't change anything on the client end unfortunately.

EDIT: The reason it screws up the servlet is because it uses the same HTTP connection and thus the same thread on my side it seems.

Comment: This can be a response state: `503 Service Unavailable
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance).[2] Generally, this is a temporary state. Sometimes, this can be permanent as well on test servers.`

Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Well, the stacktrace is not very useful, I just want to tell the client to wait instead of trying again...